# Sql query - Oracle database

Tags: sql

```
empid    emplrcd   effdt   effsq
101          #1    2/1/99    0
101          #1    3/1/13    1
101          #1    23/3/13   1 
101          #1    22/6/13   2
102          #2    20/6/91   1
```

I need to retrieve row 4, and I have written a partial code, please help me with the other half.

```
select a* 
from Ps_Job a 
where a.empid = '101' 
and a.emprcd ='#1' 
and a.effdt = (select max(a1.effdt) from Psjob1) where...............
and a.effseq = (Select  max(a2.effseq) from Ps_job2)
where..............
```

Please help me with the where caluse which should be generic and not row specific. i think it should be filled with nth max concept but not sure.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I have tried in where clause -

Comment: where (n-1) = (select count (distinct(a1.effseq) from psjob1 where a2.effseq > a1.effseq ), but the code doesn't logically fit.

Comment: @user2865419 on what conditions you want to get 4th row? based on max date and sq?

Comment: is ur requirement to get last row of same specific ID ?

Comment: @mr_eclair.. I need to retrieve based on eff seq.

Comment: @ssp, no the 4th row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In oracle**

```
select *
from 
(select a*  from Ps_Job a 
  where a.empid = '101' 
  and a.emprcd ='#1' 
  and a.effdt = (select max(a1.effdt) from Psjob1)  where ... 
  and a.effseq = (Select  max(a2.effseq) from Ps_job2)
  where ..... ) 
where ROWNUM == **The line number what you want to get**;
```

**In sql**

```
SELECT * from Ps_Job LIMIT 3,1where(

     select a*  from Ps_Job a 
      where a.empid = '101' 
      and a.emprcd ='#1' 
      and a.effdt = (select max(a1.effdt) from Psjob1)  where ... 
      and a.effseq = (Select  max(a2.effseq) from Ps_job2)
      where .....  )
```

Comment: I wonder how a statement that won't work on Oracle can be accepted as an answer to a question that says "Oracle" in the subject

Comment: it's taged as a sql so i put this one as answer

Comment: `sql` is not a specific DBMS product and relates to ANSI SQL (which doesn't have LIMIT with that syntax). But my suprise is more related to the fact that user2865419 *accepted* the answer altough it clearly could not have worked for him.